# How to get a region list in IBM cloud object storage using Rest API

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I need a Get Region List in IBM Cloud Object Storage using Rest API. For Example :us-east,au-syd etc.I didn't find any API references related to get Region List.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to retrieve the region endpoints.

Try using the following rest api call:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/[accountId]/getEndpoints
```

Output:

```
[
  {
        "legacy": true,
        "location": "us-south",
        "region": "regional",
        "type": "public",
        "url": "s3.us-south.objectstorage.softlayer.net"
    },
    {
        "legacy": true,
        "location": "us-east",
        "region": "regional",
        "type": "public",
        "url": "s3.us-east.objectstorage.softlayer.net"
    },
    {
        "legacy": true,
        "location": "eu-gb",
        "region": "regional",
        "type": "public",
        "url": "s3.eu-gb.objectstorage.softlayer.net"
    },
]
```

Reference:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Hub_Cleversafe_Account/getEndpoints/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply F.Ojeda.
But I'm getting error while trying the APi 
{"error":"Unable to find object with id of '188xxxx'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_ObjectNotFound"}.

Please let me know how to get through this error.

Comment: To get the object Storage account id by api try using the following rest api with a object filter: https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"username":{"operation":"SLOSC1232-5"}}} Replace the "SLOSC1232-5" for your username (in the control portal you will find as Account name.

Comment: Thanks F.Ojeda. Its Working fine for get SL COS Region using SL COS Acount ID. But i need IBM COS Account ID using to get region. how to get any other IBM COS API??

Comment: As I know it should work for both IBM and SL, see the following documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/cloud-object-storage-infrastructure?topic=cloud-object-storage-infrastructure-about-the-cos-api. In the following documentation you will find more examples about IBM COS API https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/cloud-object-storage-infrastructure?topic=cloud-object-storage-infrastructure-using-a-cli